# Import custom module: how can I set its path?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've just started to learn Angular 2 and I have a problem to import a custom module with interfaces declaration. This is my folder structure:

[image]

I want to import product.interface.ts into a component that it is in `app/components/product/product.component.ts` which has this import statement:

```
import { IProduct, IEmvoProduct } from '../../interfaces/product.interface'
```

I have also tried:

```
import { IProduct, IEmvoProduct } from '@app/interfaces/product.interface'
```

But it can find that module.

`product.interface.ts` is:

```
interface IProduct {
    productCode: string;
    description: string;
    lawId: number;
    name: string;
    comment: string;
    emvoProduct?: IEmvoProduct; // ?: Optional.
}

interface IEmvoProduct {
    codingScheme: string;
    name: string;
    commonName: string;
    pharmaForm: string;
    strength: string;
    packType: string;
    packSize: number;
}
```

I want to put the interfaces in a standalone file to shared between another components.

How can I import it?

Comment: Will you please post product.interface.ts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is perfect :

```
import { IProduct, IEmvoProduct } from '../../interfaces/product.interface'
```

I think you forgot to export `IProduct`, `IEmvoProduct` from the `product.interface.ts` file.

---

For error : `product.interface.ts` is not a module

Put `export` keyword before `interface IProduct` and `interface IEmvoProduct`

Like :

```
export interface IProduct {
    productCode: string;
    description: string;
    lawId: number;
    name: string;
    comment: string;
    emvoProduct?: IEmvoProduct; // ?: Optional.
}

export interface IEmvoProduct {
    codingScheme: string;
    name: string;
    commonName: string;
    pharmaForm: string;
    strength: string;
    packType: string;
    packSize: number;
}
```

Here is the link, please have a look :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-export-interface

Comment: Thanks, it works but now it said that `product.interface.ts` is not a module. I have updated my question with its content.

Comment: Put `export` keyword before `interface IProduct` and try